# Multiplication int and float(double) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to make multiplication using `JavaScript`.

Multiplication of 2 and 0.15 is 0.3 but 3 and 0.15 is 0.44999999999999996. I want to get 0.45 such as result. How can I do it with `JavaScript?`

Comment: There is no `int` or `float` in JavaScript. Everything is a `double`. That being said, you're looking for [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) if you want to convert your value into a string.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Comment: How can I get 0.45 result for multiplication 0.15 and 3?

Comment: See this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round

Comment: Yup, it is always the JavaScript, which is broken! Floating point are the same in all languages, and they obey the rules in  IEEE 754.

Comment: thanks toFixed() function is that,what I want to do

Comment: same if you add `0.15+0.15+0.15 = 0.44999999999999996`, but weird that `3.15*3=9.45` lol

Comment: you can multiply by 100 then divided by 100... so `0.15 x 100 = 15`... `15 * 3 = 45`... `45/100 = 0.45` ... but can risk overflow for large numbers

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's a rounding error. You may want to round your number to a fixed amount of digits, like this:

```
parseFloat((your_number).toFixed(2));
```

Comment: It's nice, but it produces a String FWIW!

Comment: @mplungjan Yeah, I know that, OP might not.

Comment: @limelights You have a good point, I forgot about the return type... I'll update the answer with `parseFloat`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/z4GkK/

Comment: `12.5 * 1.15` = `14.374999999999998` ---> `parseFloat(12.5 * 1.15).toFixed(2);` is `14.37` which is wrong. You need to do this: `parseFloat(parseFloat((12.5 * 1.15).toFixed(3)).toFixed(2));`

Comment: Plain vanilla solution: `new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US').format(12.5 * 1.15);`

Comment: Also, you can use: `(Math.round((12.5 + Number.EPSILON) * 100) * 1.15 / 100).toFixed(2)`

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately this happens in any language using floating point arithmetic. It's an artifact arising when floating point operations are encoded into binary, operations performed, and decoded from binary to report the answer in a form you'd expect.

Depending on what you want to do with the output, you can call a round()-like function to round to a number of decimal places or compare the output to a value using a (small) number called a *tolerance*. E.g. two numbers are considered equal if their absolute difference is less than this tolerance.