# Move dot in float number

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have some currency value `const num = '2.05';`.
I would like to receive this amount in cents. So the possible solution:

```
const num = '2.05';
const floatNum = parseFloat(num); // 2.05
floatNum * 100; // 204.99999999999997
```

The problem here in rounding, expected value `205` not `204.99999999999997`.
What I can do to resolve this:

```
const num = '2.05';
return parseInt(num.replace('.', '')); // 205
```

It will work in most cases but I have doubt that it's fully safe variant.
Would be great if someone suggest better method.

Comment: Can you not just round it back to 2.05? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiplication int and float(double) in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608146/multiplication-int-and-floatdouble-in-javascript)

Comment: You can you use round function from Math library: Math.round(parseFloat('2.05') * 100)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `Math.round` probably :https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-float-

So something like : `Math.round(2.05*100)` should alway yield `205`, then just go `%100` to drop the prefix.